# PDO duplicate insert loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, error-handling, pdo

Help.  I'm converting some code from the old mysql library to use PDO.

In several places, we attempt an INSERT knowing full well that there may be be a violation on a duplicate key.  This is fine, we look for it and continue processing.   All that works without issue.

In one place, we have to loop through and add multiple items so I'm using a prepared statement with parameter binding.  If we don't encounter any duplicates on INSERT, it works fine.  However, if there is a duplicate key violation, the following PDO->execute() fails silently, no exception, nothing.

Here is my code at present:

```
<?php
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=".$dbname, $mysqluser, $mysqlpwd,
                array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,      
                      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

$stmt = $db->prepare("insert into trials (uid,name,start_date,expire_date) values (:uid,:node,FROM_UNIXTIME(:start),FROM_UNIXTIME(:end))");
$stmt->bindValue(':uid', $uid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':node', $node, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':start', $start);
$stmt->bindValue(':end', $end);

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    if (isfreenode($node))
        continue;

    try {
        $stmt->execute();  // <-- This is where it fails
    } catch (exception $e) {
        $errorInfo = $stmt->errorInfo();
        if ($errorInfo[1] = 1062) {
            print "Trial already exists (" . $node . ") - skipping <br/>";
        } else {
            throw $e;
        }
        $stmt->closeCursor();
        continue;
    }
    print "Started Trial ( " . $uid . " , " . $node . " )" . "<br/>";
    removeRevocation($uid, $node);
    $stmt->closeCursor();
}
```

}

Any suggestions on what I can try to at least see why it's dying?

Comment: Have a look at the user comment here http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#98145 – I think you’ll have to get the _reference_ to $node in your foreach loop, so try using `foreach ($nodes as &$node)` instead. (That might require modifying your `isfreenode` function to accept a reference as well.)

Comment: If that’s not practicable for your use case, then you could also try to just use `bindValue` with $node inside your foreach loop before executing the statement.

Comment: Hmm. I don't think that's is it.  bindValue inside the loop fails in the same manner.  Also, if there is no constraint violation, the code works exactly as expected.  I'm about to just throw in the towel and make a new $stmt inside the loop.  Not so efficient, but we're not inserting large lists here.

Comment: Which works. If anyone knows why my code above doesn't work, I'd love to hear it.  Somehow I'm not resetting the $stmt object correctly after the error.

Comment: Have you tried checking if errorInfo gives anything in this case directly after executing the statement — I mean not relying on an exception being thrown, but just checking anyway?

Comment: Well, on the first iteration.  It says duplicate key, on the 2nd, it never executes. The code dies on the $stmt->execute(), without any message at all.